# Show that the $n$-torus does not have positive sectional curvature

Tags: solution-verification, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know if my attempt to show that the $n$-torus does not have

positive sectional curvature is correct.

Suppose by contradiction that the $n$-torus has positive sectional curvature.

Once that the $n$-torus is complete (because it is compact, then it is complete

by Hopf-Rinow's theorem), follows from a corollary of the Bonnet-Myer's theorem

that the fundamental group of the $n$-torus is finite, which is a contradiction

because this fundamental group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}^n,+)$. $\square$

P.S.: the corollary quoted above states that "Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian

manifold with sectional curvature $K \geq \frac{1}{r^2} > 0$. Then $M$ is

compact $\text{diam} \ M \leq \pi r$ and $\pi_1(M)$ is finite."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works. Another way of saying this is that its Riemannian universal covering admits a uniformly positive sectional curvature metric and hence is compact. But as it is $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: @Didier: Your comment seems to use the assumption that the $n$-torus is "in $\mathbb R^n$", but that assumption is itself false.

Comment: @LeeMosher Not at all, why would I suppose that? My point is that if the torus admits a positive sectional curvature metric, then by compactness, its curvature is greater than a constant $\kappa >0$. Lifting this to its universal covering (which is $\mathbb{R}^n$) yields a complete, uniformly positive sectional curvature ($\geqslant \kappa >0$) metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. By Myers theorem, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and its metric is of diameter $\leqslant \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\kappa}}$. The compacity of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is false: this is the contradiction

Comment: I missed the words "universal covering", but there they are!